# Limit CLion indexing

Tags: clion

It seems to me that CLion is always indexing the whole project. Moreover, it starts indexing again at any branch switch or pull or rebase. It's a process that never really ends in my case, because I work on a medium-large codebase.

Is there a way to limit the indexing, or at least to give priority, to the current binary or binaries whose files being edited belong to?

Comment: Do you have any large non-source directories (e.g., build directories) in your project? Make sure those directories are marked as excluded (right click > mark directory as > Excluded). Likewise, make sure library directories are marked as Library Files (otherwise CLion will try to create indexes to allow code completion and refactoring _inside_ every library source file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can limit [CLion's indexing](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/indexing.html) by selectively marking files and directories to be excluded from indexing.

To disable indexing for a specific file, you can override its file type via `Right Click` > `Override File Type`. Set the file type to Plain Text, or any other format that doesn't participate in expensive indexing.

To control indexing for entire directories, you can set directory marks. This can be done by either right-clicking the directory in the project navigator and selecting `Mark Directory As`, or by navigating to `Project` > `Project Structure` in settings and using the buttons there. For controlling indexing, the two relevant mark options are *Excluded* and *Library Files*:

- **Excluded**: don't index this directory at all. Code completion and refactoring won't be available in this directory. The contents of the directory **will not** be available in search results.
- **Library Files**: partially index this directory. Like *Excluded*, code completion and refactoring won't be available in this directory. But unlike *Excluded*, the contents of the directory **will** be available in search results.

Unfortunately, there's no way to partially/incrementally index a project with priority given to certain files. Indexing in CLion works all-at-once --- the results of the indexing are not usable until the entire indexing operation is completed. To speed up indexing when only working with a few files, you can temporarily disable indexing for unused files using the steps above.

Comment: Now there is an additional option to strict the localization of test files
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/exclude-test-directories-from-indexing.html